# objective-c replace superclass with class

Tags: objective-c

is it possible to do something like this in objective-c (using categories or something similar):
(pseudo code)

```
   abstract class Element extends Node {}

   class Object extends Element (and uses Sprite instead of Node) {}

   class Sprite extends Node {}
```

One solution would be to put Node as a member variable to Element, but then i would have to write all the wrapper functions for Node class. Is it possible to extend it somehow?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This used to be possible, but the necessary function (`class_setSuperclass`) was deprecated a long time ago and cannot be used anymore (which is probably a good thing).

There are a couple of different ways to go about this, some better than others.

The best, I think, would be to make a new `Element` subclass, called `SpriteElement`, which has a `Sprite` member variable, and then forwards on all the relevant sprite-ly methods to the internal `Sprite` instance.

You could also define a new protocol that captures all of the things you want about a `Sprite`, like so:

```
@protocol Sprite <NSObject>

- (void)doSpritelyThing;

@end
```

(I'm assuming that the `Sprite` class declares a `-doSpritelyThing` method)

Then, with a category, you could declare that the `Element` class conforms to the `<Sprite>` protocol:

```
@interface Element (Sprite) <Sprite>

@end
```

And them implement the method like so:

```
@implement Element (Sprite)

- (void)doSpritelyThing {
  ...
}

@end
```

You would probably also want to declare that the `Sprite` class conforms to the `Sprite` protocol:

```
@interface Sprite () <Sprite>

@end
```

Then in your code, instead of declaring your variables as type `Element *`, you'd declare them as `id<Sprite>` (any object that understands messages from the `<Sprite>` protocol).

---

The first approach is fine if you can be flexible with an `Element` being a different instance from a `Sprite`.  If you can't, then the second approach works great, too.

Comment: the problem is that Sprite and Node are already a interface so i would need to write wrapper functions in both cases.i'll just put Node as a member variable and the problem is solved. Thanks

Comment: Had to +1 just for "Spritely"